# How to cache pgp passphrase permanently with seahorse (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, gnupg, seahorse, pgp

I am trying to get **seahorse-daemon** (formerly seahorse-agent) to **cache** the passphrase for private pgp keys **permanently**.
I have used **dconf-editor** to set `gpg-cache-method` to always, but the setting is ignored, seahorse prompts for passphrase entry every time the key is used.
Interestingly I have six machines all running 14.04 with latest updates, and I can't figure out why some of them do cache the passphrase permanently while others don't.
Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

To permanently save the a passphrase in the keyring, use `seahorse-ssh-askpass` from package `seahorse`:

```
/usr/lib/seahorse/seahorse-ssh-askpass my_key
```

**Note:** You have to have a have the corresponding `.pub` file in the same directory as the private key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` in the example). Also, make sure that the public key is the file name of the private key plus `.pub` (for example, `my_key.pub`).